# g++ in terminal, build works but no a.out

Tags: c++, windows, terminal, g++

My code is

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    cout << "Hello";
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this using

```
g++ hello.cpp
```

There are no warnings or errors or any sort of output given. Then, I try

```
./a.out
```

which doesn't work and I check the directory to find no new files. I'm not sure what the error is since the code is so short. I know that g++ is running, but I do not know why the a.out file is not being created.

This is in Windows with MinGW, and this is the only file in the folder.

Using a.exe did not work either.

Comment: On Windows you say? Using MinGW or Cygwin? Have you tried `./a.exe`? On Windows all executable programs must end in `.exe`. It's not a requirement in many other systems (like Unix-based systems where C, C++ and the `a.out` file originated from), but it is on Windows.

Comment: @TobiSH Looks completely different to me.

Comment: On Windows, using Cygwin, I get `a.exe`, not `a.out`.  What files are in your directory?

Comment: There is no longer any good reason to use MinGW or Cygwin, and many good reasons NOT to. There is a reason WSL exists. Use it.

Comment: @torazaburo: TBH MinGW provides a good native Windows compiler, which generally has significantly better codegen than MSVC.

Comment: @MatteoItalia I am not suggesting using MSVC. I'm suggesting using Windows Subsystem for Linux, aka Bash under Windows.

Comment: @torazaburo: which doesn't create native windows executables with access to the regular Win32 APIs. (also I don't get why they call it "bash under Windows", bash is a shell and is the most irrelevant bit of the technical effort needed for WSL). WSL has its uses, but isn't comparable with a regular Win32 toolchain. Call me when I'll be able to compile my 400KLOC Win32 application under WSL (uh and it should be compatible with Windows XP or at very least Windows 7). In the meantime I'm sticking with MinGW.

Comment: @MatteoItalia Sure, but his example, at least, has nothing to do with Windows. He's (apparently) just trying to create a command-line executable, which he can run in WSL after compiling in WSL.

Comment: @torazaburo: of course; what I'm criticizing is your statement "There is no longer any good reason to use MinGW", which is complete nonsense (especially as an answer to problems regarding launching the compiler, which have nothing to do with the actual MinGW shortcomings).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the -Wall option to see if anything may be blocking the compilation? 
If not try using -o to output to an executable other than a.exe. I have had the issue where it will not output, it seems to be when I have low memory or my hard drive is in use. Try to check to see if your hard drive is in use, and if it is, wait until it's not. 
If there is still no error make sure you've installed it correctly and not missing anything.

Comment: I have tried and did not get any problems. I can try checking my hard drive, but I think I will continue using WSL.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue while working with MinGW. It turned out that I had no

```
/c/MinGW/bin
```

on `PATH`. Setting `export PATH=$PATH:/c/MinGW/bin` worked like a charm.